# Stress test a server running on the local machine?

Tags: linux, nginx, httpd, stress-testing

I tried searching around and everything gives me completely different answers

I'm comparing nginx and a proprietary server my boss wants to use. We're trying to figure out if it's a lot slower or roughly the same. Both are http servers (we don't care about https unfortunately but I'd like to check for that too)

I suspect we'll want to know number of simultaneous connections (how many can make a request every few seconds, data throughput (file transfers or dummy generated data to mock large API response) and request per second

I'm not sure if I need to know more information than that (do you have any recommendations?) but I would expect there's some open source software I can use that checks for these and generates a report?

Comment: Look at ab and siege.

Comment: @FrandsHansen ty. I vaguely remember there was a tool that gives a server bad inputs and basically fuzzes it trying to get it to crash, respond slowly or show some unescaped data on a page. I haven't read the documentation on seige or ab (I found it under the apache package). Do either tool cover fuzzing/attacking? I'll look up owasp later I think I originally found it through there. I also need to find a slowloris script/test